# Can a low rate of true positives minimise false negatives?

Tags: predictive-models, false-positive-rate, true-positive-rate

I am analysing thousands of scientific pictures which all show a similar light pattern, trying to identify local anomalies on the pictures. As it is nearly impossible to inspect each single image due to their vast number, I wrote a code that predicts the location of anomalies on the pictures. For this purpose, I divided the surface area of each picture in about 200 rectangles, and I am comparing the local median light intensity of a rectangle unit to the total median light intensity of all pictures. Outliers are defined as potential anomalies. This allows me to only inspect pictures which were flagged containing one or more outliers.

With the rectangle size chosen, the rate of true positive predictions is about 30% (individually and visually confirmed), which is obviously relative low. I can not manually quantify the number of false negatives (the number of anomalies I missed out), as the number of negative predictions is immensely high. But can I argue that the settings leading to the relatively low rate of true positive predictions potentially reduce the number of false negatives?

Comment: This isn't true in general. Consider a simple majority classifier, i.e. in your case it flags every picture as not having anomalies. This classifier minimizes true positive rate (=0) but maximizes the number of false negatives.